# Is there a way to load multiple application properties files in Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, properties, wicket

My WicketApplication.properties file has grown very large, and now to keep it more readable I want to categorize properties in different files. Is there a way to accomplish that and still access the properties like if they were all in the WicketApplication.properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See org.apache.wicket.settings.IResourceSettings.addStringResourceLoader(IStringResourceLoader).
You can implement your own IStringResourceLoader which may load from wherever your want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property files dedicated per page or even component:

- `AddressPicker.properties` - properties specific to an `AddressPicker.java` componen
- `ProfilePage.properties` - properties used only on a given page (`ProfilePage.java`)
- `WicketApplication.properties` - for aplication-wide properties (`WicketApplication.java`)

Wicket, when looking for properties for a given component, will look for the property files in the same order as above. AFAIR Struts2 uses exactly the same technic.

Please look at Wicket documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/i18n-and-resource-bundles.html.

Comment: I need more than one properties file for application level.

Comment: Well, anything that comes to my mind is to create artificial Wicket application class hierarchy (`com.example.WicketApplication` -> `com.example.AbstractWicketApplication -> ... -> `wicket.WebApplication` -> `wicket.Application`) and create a file per each one of them. Should work, thou not very elegant.

Comment: Nice "hackery" there, Tomasz :)

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you could write multiple files, but merge them into a single WicketApplication.properties as part of your build process. Unix has [a tool precisely for doing this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cat.html).